# Is there a way to do an operation on all but one member of an array?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have been working through the daily coding problems and came to this one.

> Given an array of integers, return a new array such that each element
>   at index i of the new array is the product of all the numbers in the
>   original array except the one at i.
>
> For example, if our input was [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], the expected output
>   would be [120, 60, 40, 30, 24]. If our input was [3, 2, 1], the
>   expected output would be [2, 3, 6].
>   Follow-up: what if you can't use division?

So the easy way to do this would be just to multiply all the elements in the array and then just divide by [i] but that gives the problem that if `I = 0` you are going to get an *exception* error.

I'm aware of the *aggregate* function that does an operation on all members of an array but is there a way to *modify aggregate* so that it does it to *all members but one*, or is there some other function/method that gives this functionality?

Comment: If you take advantage of LINQ you can use `Where` to grab all values that aren't 0

Comment: Do you have some code you've tried that operates on all the members?

Comment: Or use `Skip(1)` method

Comment: The examples are only correct if we assume that array indexes start at **1**. Is that the assumption that we should make, or are the examples wrong?

Comment: I think we can make that assumption.

Comment: is there no more elequant solution than to manually removing [i] from the array and then just multiplying all the members in the new array?

Comment: Manually removing an index and calculating n products is O(n^2) but if you build a [segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) you can do it in O(n log n).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `source` is small, you can skip index with a help of `Where`, e.g.

```
  int[] source = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

  int[] result = Enumerable
    .Range(0, source.Length)
    .Select(i => source
       .Where((value, index) => index != i) // all items except i-th
       .Aggregate((s, a) => s * a))         // should be multiplied 
    .ToArray();

  Console.Write(string.Join(", ", result));
```

**Outcome:**

```
  120, 60, 40, 30, 24
```

**Edit:** However, the solution has `O(N**2)` time complexity; in case the initial `source` array is *large* we can implement a more efficient `O(N)` code (and yes, we should mind *zeroes*):

```
  int[] source = ...

  int[] result;

  int zeroCount = source.Count(item => item == 0);

  if (zeroCount >= 2)      // All zeroes case
    result = new int[source.Length];   
  else if (zeroCount == 1) // All zeroes save one value case
    result = source
      .Select(v => v == 0
         ? source.Where(item => item != 0).Aggregate((s, a) => s * a)
         : 0)
      .ToArray(); 
  else {                   // No zeroes case
    // long, 1L: to prevent integer overflow, e.g. for {1000000, 1000000} input
    long total = source.Aggregate(1L, (s, a) => s * a);

    result = source
      .Select(v => (int)(total / v)) // yes, it's a division...
      .ToArray(); 
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

There are no built-in functions that aggregate on all except a single specified member (would you specify it by value or by index?)

However, a loop would be very straightforward, and Linq gives you the `Where` method where you can create *whatever predicate you want* and can then apply aggregations on the *filtered* result.

So to sum all numbers of an array instead of the third one, for example, you could do something like:

```
array.Where((x,i) => i != 2).Sum();  // use 2 since the index is 0-based
```

There's also not a built-in Linq method for `Product`, but I'm certain there's one out there, or again you could easily roll-your-own.